# How to Query Transaction on Hyperledger Sawtooth?

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I want to perform CRUD operations in Hyperledger Sawtooth.

Can I perform CRUD operations in Hyperledger Sawtooth?

Comment: If you are referring to the block chain data, then yes. You would use transaction processor(s) for CUD and REST-API and/or client app for R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform CRUD but this will be a bit different from just CRUD operations, you can only create and update or delete with the help of the transaction processor, but if you want to have a local database setup for you, then you can go to [ledger_sync sawtooth](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain/tree/master/ledger_sync) 
with this you can sync your blockchain ledger with your local database your choice, repository mentioned here is using rethinkDB but you can configure it for SQL or mongodb or any database of your choice